# R group by show count of all factor levels even when zero dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(ID = sample(letters,50,rep=TRUE))
dat %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(no_rows = length(ID))
```

I have the above code which creates a random sample of letters. However can I make the summarised output show all count levels even when there is zero.

When I run the above code sometimes I get 20 rows and sometimes I get 25, etc.
I want this to return 26 rows every time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can convert 'ID' to `factor` with `levels` specified and just use `table`

```
table(factor(dat$ID, levels = letters))
```

---

Or using the same with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
dat %>% 
  mutate(ID=factor(ID, levels = letters)) %>% 
  complete(ID) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(no_rows = n())
```

Comment: Thanks I used this. I was wondering it is possible to do this for dates too. For example of the "ID" column were months of a year, is it possible to complete using dplyr

Comment: @Chinwobble  Yes, it is possible.  Can you provide more details about how the months are represented.  If it is 1:12 then `table(factor(dat$ID, levels = 1:12))`

Comment: They are proper datetime from SQL Server. So they are in the format date object format with `yyyy-MM-dd`

Comment: @Chinwobble Then you need to extract the month i.e. `table(factor(as.integer(format(as.Date(df1$ID), "%m")), levels = 1:12))`

Comment: @HOSS_JFL  It is working fine for me.  I am not getting 1s as in your output.  May be you loaded `summarise` from `plyr` as well and it masked the output.  If the issue is from your side, please remove the statement regarding my id from your solution

Answer (score 11):

In the accepted answer by akrun, `table()` works, but the `tidyverse` answer gives inaccurate counts (see below). Instead use the `.drop = FALSE` option:

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(ID = sample(letters,50,rep=TRUE))
dat %>%
  mutate(ID = factor(ID, levels = letters)) %>%
  count(ID, name = "no_rows", .drop = F) %>%
  print.data.frame()
#>    ID no_rows
#> 1   a       3
#> 2   b       2
#> 3   c       1
#> 4   d       1
#> 5   e       3
#> 6   f       3
#> 7   g       2
#> 8   h       1
#> 9   i       2
#> 10  j       5
#> 11  k       1
#> 12  l       3
#> 13  m       0
#> 14  n       3
#> 15  o       3
#> 16  p       0
#> 17  q       0
#> 18  r       1
#> 19  s       1
#> 20  t       3
#> 21  u       3
#> 22  v       1
#> 23  w       2
#> 24  x       0
#> 25  y       5
#> 26  z       1
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Note that we expect nonzero counts for all letters but m, p, q, and x:

```r
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(ID = sample(letters,50,rep=TRUE))
levels(dat$ID)
#>  [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j" "k" "l" "n" "o" "r" "s" "t"
#> [18] "u" "v" "w" "y" "z"
```

But if we use `complete()` we get ones instead:

```r
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(ID = sample(letters,50,rep=TRUE))
dat %>% 
  mutate(ID=factor(ID, levels = letters)) %>% 
  complete(ID) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(no_rows = n()) %>%
  print.data.frame()
#>    ID no_rows
# ...
#> 12  l       3
#> 13  m       1  # should be 0
#> 14  n       3
#> 15  o       3
#> 16  p       1  # should be 0
#> 17  q       1  # should be 0
#> 18  r       1
#> 19  s       1
#> 20  t       3
#> 21  u       3
#> 22  v       1
#> 23  w       2
#> 24  x       1  # should be 0
#> 25  y       5
#> 26  z       1
```

That's because `complete()` actually adds a single m, p, q, and x to `ID` so it contains at least one of each letter.

Comment: also `count(var)` is short for `group_by(var) %>% summarize(n())`

Comment: did you mean `summarise(n())` ?

Comment: @drT `summarize` and `summarise` [both work](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise.html)

Answer (score 1):

This will also work:

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(ID = sample(letters,50,rep=TRUE))
levels(dat$ID) <- letters
as.data.frame(dat %>% xtabs(formula = ~ ID))
#   ID Freq
#1   a    2
#2   b    1
#3   c    1
#4   d    1
#5   e    2
#6   f    3
#7   g    2
#8   h    1
#9   i    4
#10  j    2
#11  k    4
#12  l    1
#13  m    2
#14  n    1
#15  o    3
#16  p    3
#17  q    3
#18  r    1
#19  s    5
#20  t    2
#21  u    1
#22  v    2
#23  w    2
#24  x    1
#25  y    0
#26  z    0
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the accepted solution by akrun I get a wrong result. I expect a frequency table with all letters with no_rows = 0 except "a" with no_rows = 1.

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(ID = "a")
dat %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(ID=factor(ID, levels = letters)) %>% 
  tidyr::complete(ID) %>%
  dplyr::group_by(ID) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(no_rows = n())
```

Instead I get a frequency table with no_rows = 1 for all letters:

```
ID    no_rows
<fct>   <int>
1 a       1
2 b       1
3 c       1
4 d       1
5 e       1
6 f       1
7 g       1
8 h       1
9 i       1
10 j      1
# ... with 16 more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

The `tidyverse` solution by akrun can be corrected as follows :

```
set.seed(1)
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: package 'tibble' was built under R version 4.0.5
dat <- data.frame(ID = sample(letters,50,rep=TRUE))
dat %>% 
  mutate(ID=factor(ID, levels = letters)) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(no_rows = n()) %>%
  complete(ID, fill = list(no_rows = 0)) %>%
  print.data.frame()
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
#>    ID no_rows
#> 1   a       3
#> 2   b       2
#> 3   c       1
#> 4   d       1
#> 5   e       3
#> 6   f       3
#> 7   g       2
#> 8   h       1
#> 9   i       2
#> 10  j       5
#> 11  k       1
#> 12  l       3
#> 13  m       0
#> 14  n       3
#> 15  o       3
#> 16  p       0
#> 17  q       0
#> 18  r       1
#> 19  s       1
#> 20  t       3
#> 21  u       3
#> 22  v       1
#> 23  w       2
#> 24  x       0
#> 25  y       5
#> 26  z       1
```